# ASP.Net core docker app throws socketException

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm spinning up a container with a service that returns a simple ping response to a GET request.

after 3 requests I get this error for every request afterwards.

only happens inside a docker container base on this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
```

when I run same app on my windows machine all works fine ...

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Connection processing ended abnormally.
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (125): Operation canceled
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.<GetResult>g__ThrowSocketException|7_0(SocketError e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.ProcessSends()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.DoSend()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token)
```

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: i'll try to create one .. right now i can't publish this code online.. 
ill try to recreate the issue a post an example